# Using recursive type aliases gives circular reference error

Tags: typescript, graphql-js

As per [TypeScript v3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases) recursive type aliases are valid to use.

```
export type IntrospectionType = {
  readonly kind: 'OBJECT';
};

export type IntrospectionListTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionTypeRef = IntrospectionTypeRef
> = {
  readonly kind: 'LIST';
  readonly ofType: T;
};

export type IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionTypeRef = IntrospectionTypeRef
> = {
  readonly kind: 'NON_NULL';
  readonly ofType: T;
};

export type IntrospectionTypeRef =
  | IntrospectionNamedTypeRef
  | IntrospectionListTypeRef
  | IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef<
      IntrospectionNamedTypeRef | IntrospectionListTypeRef
    >;

export type IntrospectionNamedTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionType = IntrospectionType
> = {
  readonly kind: T['kind'];
};
```

In this case `IntrospectionTypeRef` throws a circular reference error and hovering over `IntrospectionListTypeRef` or `IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef` says `T extends any = any` which it really shouldn't. Is there something wrong here?

Here is the link for [TypeScript playground on v4.1.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=13&pln=12&pc=40#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7GUIGcUDGMAlhBgCrKoC8cA3gFBxxTACGAJmQDaJwDWxDBwBccAOQB5AEIApAKIBhcuIDcDAL7qGoSLARV0WHPmBFSGADLFcMSigBKwAGYAeJnHJxQMYMNxG2HiEJGT2wE7OcLSYQabmYVSRDAB80fQerJw8fILCYuKWaADKKurMWVwYvHAQzuFi5OpaDDrg0PBIKIEmIRYAcmT9AK7c3OGR7sxePn4cAbG9ZqEUSS7pi8HLFhMuqemMFexVNXmiEv2S-QD6-QCqlpZqmcc5tfVUjc3auh0G3Zt4itdlFqB4AD49LYJDD9NgAW2AHBBEKhQIs1lsKOYkMBfSGQ1G4zWbg8zGYeO2QwRSJBcFxxmhK0xdhJZLgKR%207X0XVQlJhcMRyJJU083hAvn8aPxq26MUZ6MSKH2tEOLFe1VyQnO5AA2uIzuIALrfIA)

Note this code is from `graphql` we are currently in progress of [migrating Flow to TypeScript](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/2828).
Here is the [Flow equivalent](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/661ff1a6b591eea1e7a7e7c9e6b8b2dcfabf3bd7/src/utilities/getIntrospectionQuery.js#L250-L255).

Workarounds I found are:

1. Pass in `any` to `IntrospectionListTypeRef`. But that really isn't an ideal solution. See [GitHub diff](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/2828/commits/bbb08daa66255f76150f10dba382726dce42b103#diff-a40a882d49fd0a594f68d551c4ba7001ce3ddcafbf0e97debd4f8c81775a69e1)
2. Remove the generic types for `IntrospectionListTypeRef` and `IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef` then it will work but the problem is there are a few more types this way we are trying to port which would mean we are duplicating types.

Also filed an issue see [TypeScript #42308](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't allow *arbitrarily* circular type definitions.  If we look at [microsoft/TypeScript#33050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050), the pull request that introduced added support for circular type references to TypeScript 3.7, it says:

> The specific change made by this PR is that type arguments are permitted to make circular references in *aliased* types [roughly,  in type aliases] of the following kinds:
>
> - Instantiations of generic class and interface types (for example `Array<Foo>`).
> - Array types (for example `Foo[]`).
> - Tuple types (for example `[string, Foo?]`).

So something like `type Foo = Bar<Foo>` is only supported by this if `Bar` is a generic *`class`* or *`interface`*.  There is no support for when `Bar` is itself a `type` alias.

See [a comment on the same pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050#issuecomment-543365074) that explains this.  See also [microsoft/TypeScript#35017](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35017), an open feature request to lift even this restriction.

---

The easiest fix I can imagine, then, is to change every one of your `type` aliases into `interface`s where possible.  In your example code, only `IntrospectionTypeRef` itself needs to stay a `type` alias because it is a union type. All the others could be changed:

```
export interface IntrospectionType {
  readonly kind: 'OBJECT';
};

export interface IntrospectionListTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionTypeRef = IntrospectionTypeRef
  > {
  readonly kind: 'LIST';
  readonly ofType: T;
};

export interface IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionTypeRef = IntrospectionTypeRef
  > {
  readonly kind: 'NON_NULL';
  readonly ofType: T;
};

export type IntrospectionTypeRef =
  | IntrospectionNamedTypeRef
  | IntrospectionListTypeRef
  | IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef<
    IntrospectionNamedTypeRef | IntrospectionListTypeRef
  >;

export interface IntrospectionNamedTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionType = IntrospectionType
  > {
  readonly kind: T['kind'];
};

export interface IntrospectionType {
  readonly kind: 'OBJECT';
};

export interface IntrospectionListTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionTypeRef = IntrospectionTypeRef
  > {
  readonly kind: 'LIST';
  readonly ofType: T;
};

export interface IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionTypeRef = IntrospectionTypeRef
  > {
  readonly kind: 'NON_NULL';
  readonly ofType: T;
};

export type IntrospectionTypeRef =
  | IntrospectionNamedTypeRef
  | IntrospectionListTypeRef
  | IntrospectionNonNullTypeRef<
    IntrospectionNamedTypeRef | IntrospectionListTypeRef
  >;

export interface IntrospectionNamedTypeRef<
  T extends IntrospectionType = IntrospectionType
  > {
  readonly kind: T['kind'];
};
```

Now there are no errors, hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSRSggGcxhsYEIkAVAT3LgG8AoOOKYTAExoBt6cANbIeALjgByAPIAhAFIBRAMK0pAblYBfLa1CRYiFGiy4CRUuUrUkAGQQkYDcgCVg6ADzs4tOKFQkHhILGGIyCioaF2B3dDgAXlDw6yi6RliPHwA+FjgfLl4BIVEgySk7fABldS0OQr4kQTgIdBjJWi1dVn1waHhkVAwcPEIwq0jbADkaKYBXfn4YuO8OPwDgIJCxlMnojLjE5Imbfbcsjly2eu5G5tKJaSmZKYB9KYBVOztNAtvilptDIdLp6Az9OAwDLHCKndLneIJHwAHxhqWmmAAtsAeMsLnBUTsTmkHE48egUWi9kgZjSFksDh5VhwqXCpliceSCaySY5nIyKZcwX0jINTCMeRjsbiBcz1iBAsFJWc8EkibC0jEciw-kUmiUxB0ANpSB5SAC6oNYQA)